# Set Axis Limits of mixfitEM plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, mixture-model

I want to set limits to the x-axis of the plot of the output of the `mixfit` function of the `mixR` package.  This output is of class `mixfitEM`.

Reproducable example: First I simulate a mixture of log normals.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(mixR)
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(07062022)


N <- 1000
lbda=.5
mu1=1
Del=3
mu2=mu1+Del
components <- sample(1:2,prob=c((1-lbda), lbda),size=N,replace=TRUE)
mus <- c(mu1,mu2)
sds <- sqrt(c(1,.5))

Y <- rlnorm(n=N,meanlog=mus[components],sdlog=sds[components])
```

Then I try to fit two log normals into this data using `mixfit()` from `mixR`. In the first attempt I tried to use the `plot()` function from the `base` package; but `plot` ignores the `xlim` argument.

```
mod4 <- mixfit(Y, ncomp = 2, family = 'lnorm')

plot(mod4, title = 'Log-Normal Mixture (2 components)', xlim=c(0,200))
```

Then I tried to plot with ggplot, which, in theory should be possible according to the [mixR manual](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/mixR/html/plot.mixfitEM.html). But ggplot does not understand the `mixfitEM` class.

```
ggplot(mod4)+
  + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 200))
```

produces the following error:

```
> ggplot(data.frame(mod4))+
+   + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 200))
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"mixfitEM"’ to a data.frame
> ggplot(mod4)+
+   + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 200))
Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class mixfitEM.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `plot` on the `mixfitEM` object, you *are* creating a ggplot. The reason for this is that `plot` is a generic function, so when package authors create a new class, they are free to use whatever method they want to draw the plot. In this case, if you examine the source code of `mixR:::plot.mixfitEM` you will see it actually uses ggplot to draw its output. This means you can use ggplot syntax to modify the output:

```r
plot(mod4, title = 'Log-Normal Mixture (2 components)') + xlim(c(0, 200))
```

[image]